# I added elastic block storage on AWS EC2 to my VM , but I don't see it when logged in

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

According to the EC2 dashboard the EBS is attached to the instance, e.g.  attachment:  i-dc92d172:/dev/sdf (attached)
but it is not seen when I do a df -h  (only sees the root storage).

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount the disk somewhere on the filesystem. You'll probably have to partition and format the disk first too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it needs to be formatted and mounted, I found the solution here:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html